# Does the election of a Speaker of the US House of Representatives immediately install them, or can they refuse the position?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, speaker

With all the shenanigans surrounding the election of McCarthy, I got to wondering: does being elected Speaker mean that you immediately become Speaker, or do you have an opportunity to refuse? If McCarthy (or indeed anyone else) secretly felt like causing havoc, could he, on the vote falling his way, refuse to become Speaker and force yet more voting? Not "become Speaker and then immediately resign", but act in such a way that he never becomes speaker in the first place? Conversely, if there is no way to refuse, what happens if, say, someone who has no interest in being Speaker (or even actively wants to *not* be Speaker) is elected against their will?

Comment: I would assume that they could resign before swearing in members or adopting rules.

Answer (score 7):

This comes under the general heading of "Never happened, never will happen".

In theory, the House "sets its own rules".  If it decides that Kim Kardashian is to be made speaker, whether she likes it or not, then Kim is speaker (whether she likes it or not).

But that is ridiculous.

You will have noticed that the ballots don't require members to nominate themselves, Jordan repeatedly attracted votes.  You don't need to run for speaker.  I suppose it is marginally plausible that a member could be elected against their will.  If they immediately ask to stand down, then it is up to the House to decide (by voting) what to do.

However the Speaker of the House of Representatives is a powerful and sought after position. If a person who wins a ballot has a genuine reason that they are not elected, it is inconceivable that the House would ignore them.

It is utterly inconceivable that a person who has spent the last 30 years of their life building up the political support to become Speaker would, having achieved their goal, give it up *for the lols*.

If the elected speaker is unwilling, there is no procedure, and it is up to the House to decide what to do.  They could vote to "drag the representative to the chair".

Looking back, in the English Parliament (this is before the UK existed) The post of Speaker was one that brought with it a fair amount of personal danger (if and when Parliament and the King were in dispute, Kings were not above settling the argument with cold steel) And the speaker of the UK Parliament still is ceremonially dragged and forced into the chair.

Comment: Regarding *If it decides that Kim Kardashian is to be made speaker, whether she likes it or not, then Kim is speaker (whether she likes it or not).* I know you meant this as hyperbole, but I don't think that is true. If Kim Kardashian is duly elected but she refuses to take the oath, she does not become Speaker. In particular, the oath says that the person taking it takes "this obligation freely, without any mental reservation". That goes against the grain of *whether she likes it or not*.

Comment: My interpretation of that (ridiculous) situation would be that Ms Kardashian would be the speaker, but as she hasn't taken an oath, she cannot perform any other act as speaker. In the same way that a person who is elected to Congress, but refuses to take the oath is a Congressperson, but can't vote or speak etc.  This is the status of Sinn Fein MPs in the UK.  They are MPs, but as they refuse the Oath they can't take their seats.  No special elections are held in seats won by a Sinn Fein MP who refuses to take the oath.

Comment: She would be Speaker-elect but not yet Speaker. The Speaker-elect has to take the same oath administered to members-elect to become Speaker. The House Precedents allow members-elect to decline to take the oath on the grounds that people cannot be forced to take a job they do not want to undertake. The rules in the US, while derived from the rules in the UK, differ from the rules of the country from which we officially got a divorce. (It was an ugly divorce.)

Comment: "people cannot be forced to take a job they do not want to undertake"  The irony of this (in the context of 1792-1863) is noted.

Comment: Those slaves weren't quite perceived as people back then. Just 3/5 people, for the sake of counting toward Representatives, but 0 people for the sake of freedom.

Comment: In any case, we abolished that atrocity. That was an ugly  near divorce (very ugly; the most lives lost in any US war), but we reconciled. There have been joking remarks made since Britain's divorce with the EU that Britain should reconcile with the US and become the 51st to 54th states.

Answer (score 5):

A candidate for Speaker becomes the Speaker-elect (not the Speaker) upon being elected by a majority of the members-elect. The Speaker-elect does not become the Speaker until the [Speaker-elect takes the oath of office](https://www.everycrsreport.com/files/2022-12-15_RL30725_34b5e101bf8421a651b619d63f3c3b68fc447fc5.pdf). Should the Speaker-elect refuse to take the oath a new election cycle is needed.

Comment: Citation needed, in particular for the implied assertion that there is a distinct oath of office for the speaker.

Comment: @phoog Reference provided. There's a lot of pomp and circumstance on what should be the first day of Congress.